Make a tree within a field unable to be created/edited/deleted without using readonly
Code:
<field name="user_ids">
    <tree create="false" delete="false" edit="false" editable="false">
        <field name="name" />
        <field name="login" />
        <field name="login_date" />    
    </tree>
</field>

Where user_ids is a many2many field
In the view (XML), this tree does not allow me to create new records, nor delete, nor edit. Making the field readonly opens a new window when I press on a line, the idea is not to do anything when I press on it, but still, it shouldn't let me create/edit/delete?

Let's try this way:
<field name="user_ids" style="pointer-events: none;" mode="tree">
   <tree create="0" edit="0" delete="0">
      <field name="name" />
      <field name="login" />
      <field name="login_date" />    
   </tree>
</field>


Thank you for your collaboration. This option does not allow me to create/edit/delete or open the information of the line, which is fine, but visually it still appears to add a line below and delete, even though I cannot use it

Please check your XML and ensure : tree,form
also create= true in your tree view.
<record id="action_cloth_view" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">cloth</field>
    <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
    <field name="res_model">superman_j.cloth</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    <field name="target">current</field>
    <field name="help" type="html">
    </field>
</record>

